# Django: How to Add Default Location for Forms.ImageField

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I am changing my models to forms so that I can use a placeholder for my textboxes. In doing so, I am having difficulty changing the `ImageField` because it is providing me with an error that it recieved ``an unexpected keyword: default```

Here are my models.py:

```
class Project(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    #owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    bPic = forms.ImageField(default='defaultproban.jpg', upload_to='project_banner')
    logo = forms.ImageField(default='defaultlogo.jpg', upload_to='project_logo')
    dep_choice1 = (
        ('Behavioral Sciences and Leadership', ('Behavioral Sciences and Leadership')),
        ('Chemistry and Life Science', ('Chemistry and Life Science')),
        ('Civil and Mechanical Engineering', ('Civil and Mechanical Engineering')),
        ('Electrical Engineering and Comptuer Science', ('Electrical Engineering and Comptuer Science')),
        ('English and Philosophy', ('English and Philosophy')),
        ('Foreign Languages', ('Foreign Languages')),
        ('Geography and Environmental Engineering', ('Geography and Environmental Engineering')),
        ('History', ('History')),
        ('Law', ('Law')),
        ('Mathematical Sciences', ('Mathematical Sciences')),
        ('Physics and Nuclear Engineering', ('Physics and Nuclear Engineering')),
        ('Social Sciences', ('Social Sciences')),
        ('Systems Engineering', ('Systems Engineering')),
        ('Independent', ('Independent')),
    )
    department = forms.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        choices=dep_choice1,
        default='Independent',
    )
    purpose = forms.CharField(max_length=50, null = True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Write Your Mission Statement'}))
    description=forms.TextField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Briefly Describe Your Project, Progress, Goals, and Your Team!'}))
    tag_choice = (
        ('Data Analysis' , ('Data Analysis')),
        ('3D Printing' , ('3D Printing')),
        ('Robotics' , ('Robotics')),
        ('Coding' , ('Coding')),
        ('Science' , ('Science')),
        ('Drones' , ('Drones')),
        ('Math' , ('Math')),
        ('Chemistry' , ('Chemistry')),
        ('Nuclear Engineering' , ('Nuclear Engineering')),
        ('Physics' , ('Physics')),
        ('Photonics' , ('Photonics')),
        ('MATLAB' , ('MATLAB')),
        ('SolidWorks' , ('SolidWorks')),
        ('Writing' , ('Writing')),
        ('Graphic Design' , ('Graphic Design')),
        ('Design' , ('Design')),
        ('Robotics' , ('Robotics')),
        ('Business' , ('Business')),
        ('Stocks' , ('Stocks')),
        ('Hacking' , ('Hacking')),
        ('Law' , ('Law Studies')),
        ('Coding' , ('Coding')),
        ('Environmental' , ('Environment')),
        ('Lifestyle' , ('Lifestyle')),
        ('Kinesiology' , ('Kinesiology')),
        ('Health' , ('Health')),
        ('Sleep' , ('Sleep')),
        ('Psychology' , ('Psychology')),
        ('Material Science' , ('Material Science')),
        ('Batteries' , ('Batteries')),
        ('Energy' , ('Energy')),
        ('Fiber Optics' , ('Fiber Optics')),
        ('Space' , ('Space')),
        ('Autonomous Vehicles' , ('Autonomous Vehicles')),
        ('Biology' , ('Biology')),
    )

    projectTag = forms.CharField(
        max_length=32,
        choices=tag_choice,
        default='Frauds',
    )

    look = (
        ('Expert Cadets.', ('motivated cadets with niche expertise.')),
        ('Any cadet who wants to help.', ('cadets who want to learn and help.')),
        ('an engineering cadet.', ('an engineering Cadet')),
        ('a cadet with a scientific background.', ('a cadet with a scientific background')),
        ('cadets with programming experience.', ('cadets with programming experience')),
        ('Stem interests.', ('cadets with an interest in STEM.')),
        ('scholarship', ('cadets seeking scholarships from research')),
        ('a lot of work.', ('cadets who can work 10-20 hours a week')),
        ('anyone', ('anyone!')),
    )
    
    lookingFor = forms.CharField(
        max_length=75,
        choices=look,
        default='an engineering cadet,',
    )

    recruit = (
        ('Yes', ('Yes')),
        ('No', ('No')),
    )

    recruiting = forms.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        choices=recruit,
        default='Yes',
    )
    statusOptions = (
        ('Active', ('Active')),
        ('Archived', ('Archived')),
        ('Deleted', ('Deleted')),
    )

    status = forms.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        choices=statusOptions,
        default='Active',
    )
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural= "projects"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Thanks and please let me know if any other part of the code would help you but this should be good.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use **default** keyword or **upload_to**, this is not a model.

if you want to save the image you should use a model and specify name and upload location there.